# Best way to share hibernate configuration across projects

Tags: java, hibernate

We have couple different web-apps that share the same db link. The hibernate layer in each web-app is a jar copy of the "*.hbm.xml" and java files. Over time, I am worried about inconsistencies creeping into each copy, people forgetting to create jar file.

Is there a better way to share the same db hibernate information across multiple projects than just creating jar files ?

Comment: If you are using [tag:maven] then sharing a JAR file across several projects is the right way to go, no to mention you get full versioning support.

Comment: I echo Tomasz's comment. We do this and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely a build & deployment problem. If your hibernate entities are in a different package, then you should build that package before the apps, and package the resulting jar with them.

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) makes this easy:

- a multi-module project
- a jar-packaged module that contains the entities
- war-packaged modules that have a `<dependency>` on the jar
- the same version across all modules.

Comment: I was thinking this is the only possible way. From what I read, it does simplify things but this is a small development shop with no resources for such things. I guess I can actually use svn:extensions as well and pull the same source across multiple projects. Not sure which is easier....